# primefaces p:selectOneMenu doesn't display right

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I work with primefaces. I have the follwing p:selectOneMenu

```
<h:form id="frmFiltros" styleClass="form-filtros">
            <p:panelGrid columns="5" style="margin:auto;">
                <h:outputLabel for="txtHoraRef" value="A partir de:" />
                <p:spinner id="txtHoraRef" value="#{servComp.horaReferencia}" min="0" max="23" size="4"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="cbIntervalo" value="Rango de horas:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="cbIntervalo" value="#{servComp.intervalo}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{servComp.intervalos}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="Listado" action="#{servComp.doListado}" update=":pnlDiagrama" oncomplete="configTabla();"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

When I execute the screen, it doesn't display right. The screen is:

[image]

Is a style primefaces problem?

Comment: could you also provide a code sample of the bean you used?

Comment: This  drop down displayed  right some days before. It happens the same in all project's selectOneMenu

Comment: Better yet, create a [mcve]... Mostlikely custom css that messes things up